# Magia Record: Why did the screenwriters cut the original Quintet out so much?

Tags: madoka-magica

So I was wondering when starting to play the Magia Record Game that there was quite some differences to the now airing anime adaption.
While in the game the quintet from the original series (homura, madoka, sayaka, mami and kyouko)
plays a leading role in Kamihara - the Anime until now decided to almost cut them out entirely from the plot.
(Yes, Mami made an appearance last episode and Kyouko did for one episode, but the role they took was rather minor and differs from the Plot of the game source).
Just like Iroha in the Anime has not yet even met Homura and Madoka who play a major role in the game to be able to free Sana.

So to my question: **Is there any reason in particular the screenwriters decided to cut the original Quintet out so much?** Do they maybe want the audience to focus more on the new girls?
Cause it feels like they're rewriting big chunks of plot just to be able to leave them out in the adaption.